# I want to extract and copy the resID from the reservation sheet in the occupancy sheet if the checkIn date matches the date in occupancy sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to extract and copy the reservation ID from the reservation data sheet to a single cell in the occupancy sheet, into the column with the same date as the checkIn date using the google app script.
For e.g.

1. my resID is 101, my booking date is 4/1/23, and my checkIn date is 4/2/23.
2. then in the Occupancy sheet I want to extract and copy my resID to the checkIn date under the column name "date"(4/2/23) in one cell.

reservation sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hoXhPAHOovXvcLQED5aFTQIUnTr4SC6JvyC2na3Npu8/edit?usp=sharing

Occupancy sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nTKL17Vgmx5gVsBcePHcmF_6ecfDswP3MS7NhXRSo-M/edit?usp=sharing .

```
function updateCell() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hoXhPAHOovXvcLQED5aFTQIUnTr4SC6JvyC2na3Npu8').getSheetByName('RS1');
var startRow = 2;  
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   
var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, numColumns);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
//var ssRow = ss.getRange().getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
//var row = data[i];
//var resId = row[0];
//var checkIn = row[2];  
//var checkOut = row[3];
//var bookingStatus = row[5];
if (data[i][5] == 'Confirmed') {
var totalCell = ss.getRange('ad2');
totalCell.setValues(data[i][0]);
}
}  
}
```

I tried setting values of resId in AD2 cell of occupancy sheet and my coding is executing successfully but I cannot see any output in my occupancy sheet.
I am very new to googles app script and I request your help.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your 2 sample Spreadsheets, I cannot understand `For e.g. 1. my resID is 101, my booking date is 4/1/23, and my checkIn date is 4/2/23. 2. then in the Occupancy sheet I want to extract and copy my resID to the checkIn date under the column name "date"(4/2/23) in one cell.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: Welcome. Your question needs to stand on its own. Thank you for providing a spreadsheet but please don't expect that users should/must/will look at the spreadsheets to understand you question. Details such as the sheets, data content, layout, etc should be explained/described in the body of your question. That's also where you would provide sample data (in table form) and, as Tanaike points out, an example of a successful outcome for your script.

Comment: Guest_Name Kiruthika Chelliah
Check_In         10/2/2022
Check_Out 10/4/2022
Room_type Suite Room             ------------ This is the input data.

Comment: In the output we need to update row_x column_y(fill color to be added in the particular cell) based on the rows(date series) on check_In and check_Out as well as room_type (room type is mentioned in the rows) (different room types have different row numbers) -----Thank you for the quick response and for the help so far. ----------https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s4nIRfd14gtf2eRH2Y4t-v0NIywTHMsY/view?usp=share_link  (example of occupancy sheet which is to be updated with the result)